# In an Ember Array, how do i access object by index value? Ember Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

For an ember array you can simply do this:

```
array.get('firstObject');
```

to get the first object in array.

or this:

```
array.get('lastObject');
```

to get last object in array.

How do I get something by its index? similar to how it works in an ordinary javascript array:

array[index];

Answer (score 26):

Looking at the documentation, you could just do `var myObject = array.objectAt(someIndex);`, and that will return the object at that specific index. You can [check the documentation here.](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt)

Answer (score 1):

```
array.get(index)
```

actually works.  `index` can be either an integer or a string.

---

It also works for array-properties, ie.

```
this.get('myArray.1')
```

will return the second element in the `myArray` property.

Comment: Great, thank you. Also `this.get('myArray').get(1)` works!

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert: The problem with that is that it will throw an exception if `myArray` is null or undefined, whereas `this.get('myArray.1')` will not. If you _want_ an exception to be thrown, there is also `this.get('myArray')[1]`, or even (if you know `myArray` is not a computed) `this.myArray[1]`